# How to get image from java webservice on Android

Tags: java, android, mysql, json, web-services

I have a Java (JAX-RS) webservice which stores images in mysql blob. 
Using a GET request get a JSON or XML with the image but that.

```
[{"id":1,"imagen":"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAKAAAABfCAYAAABvC8zhAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAGO5JRE ...etc
```

My question is: 
Is it a good idea to get that JSON in my android application and store the text sen a variable? How could I create a bitmap from that text? Would it be very slow? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First answer to your question is: Absolutely yes. JSON is a better way to get data compare to XML.

Secondly, From your JSON `String` , it seems like image is `Base64` encoded. So parse the JSON and decode `Base64` `String` to get image `Bitmap` using `BitmapFactory` like this way:

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
```

For parsing JSON:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length;i++){
   JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
   String id = jsonObj.getString("id");
   String encodedString = jsonObj.getString("imagen");
   Log.i("DATA","Id: "+id);
}
```